# LISTAGG fails with sqlcode=-433

Tags: db2, maxlength, listagg

How to overcome from length issue on ListAGG function.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [XMLAGG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022183.html) function instead:

```
select 
--length (
substr(xmlserialize(
xmlquery('$L/text()' passing XMLAGG(xmlelement(name "a", ','||colname)) as "L") as clob(2M)
), 2)
--)
from syscat.columns;
```